# Unit test - check on Empty

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I developed Unit test for my service. Now my test check on inserting Name and 2nd check on a null.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task InsertTownName_ReturnTownName()
{
    var builder = new RepositoryBuilder<TownRepository>().SetupManager();

    using (builder.CreateIsolationScope())
    {
        var repository = builder.Build();

        var townName = "Town" + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();

        await repository.InsertTown(townName);

        var connection = builder.TransactionManager.Connection;
        var transaction = builder.TransactionManager.Transaction;

        var result = await connection.ReadSingleOrDefaultAsync<Town>(x => x.Name == townName, transaction: transaction);

        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.AreEqual(townName, result.Name);
    }
}
[TestMethod]
public async Task InsertNullName()
{
    var builder = new RepositoryBuilder<TownRepository>().SetupManager();

    using (builder.CreateIsolationScope())
    {
        var repository = builder.Build();

        await repository.InsertTown(null);

        var connection = builder.TransactionManager.Connection;
        var transaction = builder.TransactionManager.Transaction;

        var result = await connection.ReadSingleOrDefaultAsync<Town>(x => x.Name == null, transaction: transaction);

        Assert.IsNull(result.Name);
        Assert.AreEqual(null, result.Name);
    }
}
```

Both of this method works good. Next step **I need check on Empty** (If in line where user need insert town name - empty name). I have no idea how implement it. Could You recommend to me and could you check 2nd method for working with null. Is it correct unit test? Here my method that I tested

```
public async Task<int> InsertTown(string townName)
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(townName))
{
    throw new Exception();
}
else
{
    var parameters = new { townName };

    return await Connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<int>(Adhoc["AddTown"], parameters, Transaction);
}
```

Comment: Looks like your unit tests are more like integration tests. If you're testing the `InsertTown` method then you would need to mock any dependencies and test that `QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync` is being invoked with the correct parameters.

Comment: The `InsertTown` method should check incoming parameters for correctness and throw an exception.

Comment: Hm, if I do something like If-Else block with check "IsNullOrEmpty" in my method. How can I implement it in my test ? I updated my method.

Comment: Now my test for testing null inserting is failed. How I need change implementation of my test method to work with exception

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what a method with input parameters checking might look like.

```
public async Task<int> InsertTown(string townName)
{
    if (townName == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(townName));
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(townName))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Parameter cannot be empty", nameof(townName));
    }

    var parameters = new { townName };
    //return await Connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<int>(Adhoc["AddTown"], parameters, Transaction);
    return await Task.Run(() => 42); // for testing puprposes
}
```

You can test it like this

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task InsertTown_NullString_ThrowsArgumentNullExceptionAsync()
{
    string townName = null;
    // var repository = ...;

    await Assert.ThrowsExceptionAsync<ArgumentNullException>(() =>
        repository.InsertTown(townName));
}

[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow("")]
[DataRow(" ")]
public async Task InsertTown_EmptyString_ThrowsArgumentExceptionAsync(string value)
{
    string townName = value;
    // var repository = ...;

    await Assert.ThrowsExceptionAsync<ArgumentException>(() =>
        repository.InsertTown(townName));
}
```

---

As mentioned in the comments, it looks like your unit tests are more like integration tests.
In unit tests, you should not access neither real database, work with a network, nor work with a file system.
You have to mock any dependencies. For example with NSubstitute, FakeItEasy or Moq.

---

Your `Connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync` method is static, right?
It is highly recommendable to rewrite the code, getting rid of static methods. With the extraction of abstractions to interfaces. Because static methods, like in your case, are untested or difficult to test.